# Абстракция в Java

Tags: java, ооп

Читаю про ООП и там сказано , что у ООП есть 3 основных основных понятия. Это инкапсуляция, полиморфизм и наследование.

Так же сказано , что к ним еще можно отнести абстракцию. Про первые три понятия я понял , а вот про абстракцию что то вообще ничего не пойму. Можете на  каком то понятном примере объяснить , что такое абстракция в ООП ? (Книга   : "ОО Анализ и Проектирование" , Гради Буч ).

У первых трех понятий есть конкретное применение в языке , а про абстракцию читаю только в теории и не пойму зачем она и какой в ней смысл ?

Comment: [Абстракция данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Answer (score 17):

Отличный вопрос! 
чтобы понять, что такое Абстракция можно почитать пару статей  из интернета ([один](http://kostin.ws/java/java-abstract-and-interfaces.html), [два](http://programm.ws/page.php?id=233)).

Но по сути достаточно запомнить следующее:

(абстракция  будет возрастать с каждым пунктом)

1) 
**instance** (Объект)              сущность обладающая набором характеристик свойственных конкретному экземпляру класса. Имеет конкретные значения полей  (низший уровень, без абстракции)

---

2)
**class** (класс)    описание множества объектов схожих по свойствам и внутренней структуре (шаблон для создания объектов).

---

3)
**abstract class** (Абстрактный класс) -  абстрактное описание характеристик множества классов (выступает как шаблон для наследования другими классами). Имеет высокий уровень абстракции, в связи с чем,  от абстрактного  класса нельзя создавать объекты напрямую* (только через создание объектов от классов наследников)

Внутри абстрактного класса могут присутствовать методы с реализацией 
(но не обязательно)

4) **interface** (Интерфейс) - это конструкция языка программирования Java, в рамках которой могут описываться только абстрактные публичные  методы (abstract public) и статические константы свойства (final static). То есть также, как и на основе абстрактных классов, на основе интерфейсов нельзя порождать объекты.

**upd:** Начиная с Java 8 кроме абстрактных методов и констант мы также можем использовать в интерфейсах стандартные методы (default methods) и статические методы (static methods).

---

---

немного о реализации:

---

**классы в java не поддерживают множественное наследование**(это касается и абстрактных классов), поэтому могут наследоваться (напрямую), лишь от одного родителя:

```
class Имя_класса_наследника extends Имя_класса_родителя {
     // реализация  
}
```

за-то **класс может реализовывать множество интерфейсов**

```
class Имя_класса implements интерфейс_1, интерфейс_2, ... ,интерфейс_N {
 // реализация методов интерфейсов 
 // и реализация собственных методов
}
```

**Один интерфейс может быть наследником (может расширяться) нескольких  интерфейсов**:

```
interface интерфейс_1 extends интерфейс_2, интерфейс_3, ... , интерфейс_N {
   //описание методов и полей для интерфейс_1
   //также методов и поля будут взяты из интерфейсов интерфейс_2 ... интерфейс_N
}
```

Классы могут реализовывать интерфейсы (т. е. получать от интерфейса список методов и описывать реализацию каждого из них), притом, что особенно важно, **один класс может реализовывать сразу несколько интерфейсов**:

```
class Имя_класса implements интерфейс_1, интерфейс_2, ... ,интерфейс_N {
 // реализация методов интерфейсов 
 // и реализация собственных методов
}
```

Класс может напрямую наследовать свойства и методы, только от одного родительского класса (**extends**), и одновременно с этим, он может реализовывать множество интерфейсов (**implements**):

```
class Имя_класса extends Имя_класса_2 implements интерфейс_1,интерфейс_2,...,интерфейс_N {
 // реализация методов интерфейсов 
 // реализация собственных методов
 // переопределение методов родительского класса
}
```

---

**Вывод**: так как **интерфейс** схож с абстрактным классом, но позволяет (неявно) выполнить множественное расширение - он **имеет максимальный уровень Абстракции**

Answer (score 2):

Применительно к Java абстракция реализована посредством `abstract class` и `interface`

Answer (score 2):

1. Абстракция - это способ, которым мы умеем взаимодействовать с окружающим миром, познавать его. Мы мыслим абстракциями. Мы не воспринимаем объект всегда во всей его сложности, а упрощаем его до той степени, которой требует крнкретная ситуация. Дантисту, к которому пришел пациент А.А.Иванов, обсолютно все рано на тонкую душевную организацию и всестороннюю развитость личности А.А.Иванова. А.А.Иванов для него - это состояние зубов, реакция на анастезию и количество денежных знаков для оплаты услуги. Т.е. абстракция - это отделение существенного от несущественного в конкретном контексте.
2. Выше - это про то, что такое абстракция в общем. Если спуститься к Java, то здесь абстракция реализована в виде абстрактных классов и интерфейсов. Это нужно для отделения интерфейса (звучит тафтологически, но по-другому сформулировать не могу) от реализации. Это необходимо для уменьшения связанности и увеличения гибкости системы.
3. D в принципах SOLID а также Indirection и Protected Variations в паттернах GRASP  - это все как раз про абстракцию и интерфейсы.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо на этот вопрос ответил Герберт Шилдт. В то время как инкапсуляция, полиморфизм и наследование являются принципами ООП, абстракция — это элемент ООП. Она стоит над принципами ООП. Принципы ООП реализуют абстракцию.
Абстракция в контексте ООП — это главное свойство класса, которое заключается в выделении важных черт в контексте поставленной задачи и отбрасывании неважных.

Comment: Водички много, и это все теория.